# Error using Moq's Verify method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am experiencing an issue with Moq in my unit testing and I am not sure where I am going wrong.
I have a method in my interface with like this:

```
void WriteToRegistryKey (String key, Object value);
```

and I am unit testing it like this:

```
var testRegistry = new Mock<IRegistry>();
testRegistry.Setup(x => x.WriteToRegistryKey(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()));

Utility testUtility = new ConfigUtil(testRegistry.Object);

testUtility.UpdateRegistry();

testRegistry.Verify(x => x.WriteToRegistryKey("MaxNumLogFiles", 10));
```

Under the hood when I call testUtility.UpdateRegistry() it calls my WriteToRegistryKey I want to test that WriteToRegistryKey 
method passing in the correct values.

However I receive this when I run the test:

```
Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.WriteToRegistryKey("MaxNumLogFiles", (Object)10)

Configured setups:
x => x.WriteToRegistryKey(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<Int32>()), Times.Never

Performed invocations:
IRegistry.WriteToRegistryKey("MaxNumLogFiles", 10)
```

If I change my testRegistry.Verify to:

```
testRegistry.Verify(x => x.WriteToRegistryKey("MaxNumLogFiles", It.IsAny<object>()));
```

it works, so the issue seems to be around the second parameter the WriteToRegistryKey method takes, and the difference between int and object, but I cant seem
to figure it out.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: In the signature of WriteToRegistryKey you have Object as the Type for value....thus anyone passing an int "value" to your WriteRegistryKey it will be implicitly boxed (i.e. become an object)...I guess this is affecting the Verify.

Comment: I think the issue is around this area to, I don't want to change anything about the WriteToRegistryKey method though, it must be possible to test it as it is somehow using Moq...

Comment: testRegistry.Setup(x => x.WriteToRegistryKey(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>( v => (v is int) ))); ... don't know if that will work....or do something similar in the lambda expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the body of implementation of `testUtility.UpdateRegistry();` how the `.WriteToRegistryKey` method is called there.

However: 
I would **remove** the line where you setup the `testRegistry` mock:
`testRegistry.Setup(x => x.WriteToRegistryKey(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()));`
Because, you want to test it, if it was called with correct arguments or not. There is no reason to setup that with Moq.

and if your test passes with 
`testRegistry.Verify(x => x.WriteToRegistryKey("MaxNumLogFiles", It.IsAny<object>()));`

It could mean two things:

1. Your WriteToRegistryKey method is called with other then **10** value - error in UpdateRegistry method
2. or it's null, because you setup it with:

`It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()`

When you use `It.IsAny<type>()` it could be also `null`.

Comment: Some very helpful information in here thats helped me understand the tests better, thank you Adronius.